# How do I animate between CSS classes using ngAnimate?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

In my app, I want to show a loading indication during loading. I have implemented this successfully:

```
lyr.ui.directive('loading', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('content-loading');
        var unbind = scope.$watch(attr.loading, function(value) {
            if (value) {
                element.removeClass('content-loading');
                element.addClass('content-loaded');
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.removeClass('content-loaded');
                }, 250);
                unbind();
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/L6opqA?p=preview

However, I think I'm duplicating a lot of ngAnimate code in adding and removing classes, and in hard-coding the removal of `content-loaded` using a hard-coded timeout.

**Is it possible to convert my example to use ngAnimate with less *duplicated* code?**

It's hard to figure this out myself because the documentation on ngAnimate does not focus on JS-triggered animations.

Small note that is not reflected in the plunker: I have to render the element's children during loading, because the element contains a jQuery plugin that calls `$.width`, which would return 0 for elements that aren't rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [another plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zs495osfSnWSvWBIn3rh?p=preview) that showed me how to do this.

Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/bzIReo?p=preview

```
myApp.directive('loading', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.addClass('content-loading');
        var unbind = scope.$watch(attr.loading, function(value) {
            if (value) {
                $animate.removeClass(element, 'content-loading');
                unbind();
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.content-loading {
    background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 20px 10px;
}

.content-loading > * {
    opacity: 0;
}

/* Class name generated by ngAnimate */
.content-loading-remove > * {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 250ms linear;
    transition: opacity 250ms linear;
    opacity: 1;
}
```